# CSS for setting up figcaption format for Fig. Chapter number-Figure number

Tags: css, epub

I'm editing an `ePub` and I need to set up the figures so that the caption has the format:

```
                +=========+
                |  image  |
                +=========+
            Fig. 8-1: My Image
```

I'm familiar with using CSS counters to reset a counter, increment it, and to insert it into this format:

Fig. 1: My Image

However, I've spent half a day looking through Google and a host of other sites trying to see how to do this with no success.

Any help/pointers/etc. appreciated!

Comment: That will entirely depend on the structure. CSS Counters are **highly** structure sensitive. Frankly, I'm not sure they are a good option here...even if ePub supports them

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Tough to provide an MWE when I'm asking about how to implement something that I'm considering. My best guess would be to have CSS that looks something like:

body { counter-reset: FigCount; }

.figure { counter-increment: FigCount; }

.figure figcaption:before { content: 'Figure ' counter(FigCount) ': '; }

which would give me something like:

   Figure 1: blah blah blah

when I use the HTML:

<figure>
  <img src=...>
  <figcaption>blah blah blah</figcaption>
</figure>

Comment: The format that I'd like to achieve is the one mentioned, i.e.,  Figure <chapter>-<figure number>: caption

This sort of thing is relatively simple in LaTeX, but HTML/CSS just aren't quite to that level without a lot of base hackery (which is what I'm looking for help with) because .epub/.mobi settled on XHTML/CSS as their basis.